# When to use continuation token to paginate in CosmosDB?

Tags: c#, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

Reading the MS doc on [Pagination in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-pagination) it's mentioned:

> When query results cannot be returned in one single execution, Azure Cosmos DB will automatically split results into multiple pages

and further on specifies that:

> In some cases, it is also possible that your query may return an empty page of results.

So seems like the DB + client will handle pagination for us, but not always??

Using this option, one needs to check if there are more pages to check for via:

```
query.HasMoreResults
```

The doc also mentions that:

> You can optionally use continuation tokens to manage query results that span multiple pages.

So when should you use a continuation token?
I'm planning on running frequent DB calls to fetch ALL the DB content (< 10MB) frequently, and am concerned about getting throttled.

Comment: "*So when should you use a continuation token?*" if you need to make another call in a different context. If you are worried about throttling and limits, look at the caching this data, also continual 1 gig queries seems like a suboptimal approach to anything, i would rethink your design if its possible

Comment: The data fetched is actually 1MB currently. 1GB is the absolute worst case couple of years down the line (and yes in that case the solution needs to be re-thought). Caching the data is not an option, as the intent of the fetches is to continuously warm the cache every few minutes.

Comment: Anyway to answer the question, the tokens are just that, a token that never expire, you could conceivably make a call, read some data, go make a coffee, paste the token in another application and continue the paging. I am not sure much more can be added to an answer

Comment: I'm guessing the "optionally" language is a bit misleading, as it implies there might be another way to get all the pages. AFAIK, a more accurate phrase would be "use continuation tokens if your results might span multiple pages and you want all the results by a sequence of multiple queries."

Answer (score 3):

If the query spans multiple pages you have 2 options (hence the word "optionally"):

1. You can drain all the pages and all the results in the same operation that started the query, with a loop on `HasMoreResults`:

```
while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<T> response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    // do something with the page contents
}
```

2. If you have an architecture where the paging across results is not immediate (like for example showing a user pages of results and they manually go to the next page), you can pass the Continuation of the current page to the calling component, and when the calling component decides it's time to get the next page, just use the Continuation creating a new iterator and getting the next page.

It depends on your business scenario which one you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also put up a self answer referencing your post.

Answer (score 1):

After doing more reading, I understand the reasoning behind continuation token and its use.

It's worthy to note that CosmosDB didn't always support skipping. Back then you couldn't [`OFFSET` and `LIMIT` queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit), there weren't any keywords to allow you manually page or query a specific range of items from DB. The SDK provided continuation tokens instead to allow you do that.

Using continuation token, you have a marker for where a page stopped. And as long as you're using the same connection, you can query items from a point of continuation over and over.
So if you wanted to query items starting at a point instead of all items, you can store the continuation token for it and reuse it some time later. It also allows you to page on demand, so you don't have to fetch all items all at once - Matias gives a good example of that [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68329154/3411556).

In other scenarios, where you don't care about wanting to page from a specific point, or more than once, you can simply follow the recommended way to loop till `HasMoreResults` is `false`. [Here is a sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.asdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet#examples) of the pattern:

```
using (var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(
    collectionLink,
    new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 })
    .Where(b => b.Title == "War and Peace")
    .AsDocumentQuery())
{
    while (queryable.HasMoreResults) 
    {
        foreach(Book b in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>())
        {
            // Iterate through books
        }
    }
}
```